# Rails 5 has_many with jsonb foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model that has a `has_many` and I'm trying to use a jsonb column as the foreign key.
I'm using postgres as the database.

```
has_many :accounts, foreign_key: "item->>'Id'", primary_key: "item->>'AccountId'"
```

The SQL comes out like this (notice the quotations around the join fields where it is 
`"accounts"."item->'Id'"`

```
SELECT "opportunities".* FROM "opportunities" INNER JOIN "accounts" ON "accounts"."item->>'Id'" = "opportunities"."item->>'AccountId'" WHERE "opportunities"."item->>'AccountId'" IS NULL
```

I've tried the below, which works, but the primary keys are actually ignored (likely due to the `unscope` call).

```
  has_many :accounts, ->{
    joins("inner join opportunities on opportunities.item->>'AccountId' = accounts.item->>'Id'").unscope(:where)
  }, foreign_key: "item->>'Id'", primary_key: "item->>'AccountId'"
```

Without the `unscope` call, the following select statement is produced:

```
SELECT "accounts".* FROM "accounts" inner join opportunities on opportunities.item->>'AccountId' = accounts.item->>'Id' WHERE "accounts"."item->>'Id'" IS NULLs
```

Aside from duplicating the association data into a column, any idea how to make this work?